# Should we stay or pay the exit fee given the utility function

Tags: finance, utility

You have invested $10\%$ of your wealth in a hedge fund; the other $90\%$ is in cash and there is no time value of money. One year from now the hedge fund will cease operations; it will either fail and give you back only half of your investment, or succeed and give you back 1.85 times your investment. You know that $15\%$ of hedge funds fail every year.

You find a hedge fund evaluation model which, if applied to funds that are going to fail, says they will fail $95\%$ of the time. If the model is applied to funds that will succeed, then it says they will succeed $90\%$ of the time. You run this model on your hedge fund and it says it will fail. You can get your money out now for a $2\%$ exit fee. If you have a logarithmic utility function, should you exit now or stay for the remaining year?

Let $w$ be the $10\%$ wealth that we have invested in the hedge fund. I have set up the utility function if we stay: $$0.95\times\log{0.5w}+0.05\times\log{1.85w}$$
The utility function if we exit: $\log{0.98w}$. Thus we should exit. Can anyone confirm my work? I feel uncertain since I'm not using all the information provided...

Comment: Presumably the utility function takes your total wealth as the argument, so you have to add in the $9w$ you have in cash.  The 0.95 and 0.05 are not quite right.  They are the chances of the model output when applied to a bunch of funds.  You are asked for the chance the fund will fail given that the model says it will.  These are not the same thing.

Comment: Sounds like Bayes' Theorem to me. I would appreciate if you take a look at this:  $P(fail|test=fail)=\frac{P(test=fail|fail)P(fail)}{P(test=fail|fail)P(fail)+P(test=fail|succeed)P(succeed))}$. Then I suppose I use this number instead of 0.95, right?

Comment: I think that is the right formula, but I haven't studied it in a long time.